# jenkins shell: check for mounted path existence fails

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to check if a folder in mounted partition exists using execute shell in jenkins build.

```
if [ ! -d "/media/muralidhar/DATA1/test" ]; then
 echo "$destination_directory does not exists"
fi

if [ -d "/var/www/html/" ]; then
 echo "$source_directory exists"
fi
```

The output of the build is as given below:

```
[shell_test] $ /bin/bash -xe /tmp/hudson8078612261658226967.sh
+ '[' '!' -d /media/muralidhar/DATA1/test/ ']'
+ echo 'folder /media/muralidhar/DATA1/test/ does not exists'
folder /media/muralidhar/DATA1/test/ does not exists
+ '[' -d /var/www/html/ ']'
+ echo 'folder /var/www/html/ exists'
folder /var/www/html/ exists
Finished: SUCCESS
```

While the same code works in terminal, jenkins shell says the directory does not exists. Interestingly directory listing (ls) seems to be working for the same directory (only with sudo) in jenkins shell.

How do I check if mounted path/directory exists using jenkins shell?

Additional Information:

1. Jenkins shell is executed by the user jenkins
2. The partition was mounted when I ran this code
3. I have changed Shell executable to bash in the Jenkins configurations. Value set is /bin/bash
4. jenkins user is added to visudo. The entry for jenkins is as given below:

`jenkins    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`
5. Mounted partition filesystem is NTFS

Update:

1. If I run the shell script as jenkins user in terminal I get the same output as what was seen in the build console
2. Likewise, in execute shell section of jenkins build if I run `test` using sudo I get the correct result.

`sudo test -d "/media/muralidhar/DATA1/test/" && echo Exists || echo Does not exist`

From the looks of it jenkins user does not have permission to read the folder and it's contents (even though the folder has 777 permissions)

3. For now I am running all the commands in the jenkins shell by switching to system user:

`exec sudo -u systemuser /bin/bash - << 'EOF'`

Any alternative solutions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Jenkins user has read permissions to the mounted directory.

Comment: The folder I am trying to check for and it's parent folder both have 777 permissions